# Unable to change number of vertices after adding a bezier circle in blender 2.83

Tags: vertices

Once I add a bezier circle, there is no option to change the number of vertices anywhere. As you can see, the box at the bottom has no option to add vertices. If I click edit mode, the bottom box also disappears. I am a beginner in blender so a detailed reply will be helpful. Also, once the circle is added, I have pressed F6 (as suggested in other answers) but nothing happened.[image]

Comment: You are right. If you add a bezier circle, there is no option to change the amount of vertices anywhere. What's your question? Do you want to add bezier points? Do you want a mesh circle with a specific amount of vertices? Try adding a mesh circle maybe. Also please ask a clear question in addition to stating and defining an issue.

Comment: @R-800 Regarding your edit, I think it's best not to correct 'circle' to 'bezier circle'. The user did not entirely realise they were adding a bezier circle, which was part of the issue. If other users have a similar issue and search for this question they may ignore it if they also didn't realise they were adding a curve ("This question doesn't relate to *my* problem, because *I* was adding a mesh").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have added a *curve* circle, instead of a *mesh* circle. A curve circle does not have vertices, it has control points, but these cannot be adjusted when adding the object. A *mesh* circle will have the option to adjust the number of vertices.

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>> *Mesh> Circle* to add a mesh circle. Then the *Adjust Last Operation* panel (the panel in the bottom left) will show the option to adjust the vertices.

Comment: This is my very first day in blender. I was learning a tutorial online and got stuck here. I kept adding curve circle instead of mesh circle and did not realize probably because I did not know there existed two concepts! However, your prompt reply helped me to move ahead with my learning (already spent 1.5hrs on this!). Thankyou!!